# session variable is empty on second page (pagination) in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am trying to add this array to my codeigniter session variable:

```
        $formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
        $fv = $this->session->set_userdata($formValues);


        if (!$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE)) {
        echo "false, post is null, get the session";

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($fv);
        echo "</pre>";

        } else {
        echo "true, use the post";
        $formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
         echo "<pre>";
        print_r($formValues);
        echo "</pre>";

        } 


print_r($formValues);
<pre>
Array
(
    [addtypeid] => 
    [isnew] => 
    [orderby] => 
    [geographicareaid] => 
    [catid] => 1
    [catid2] => 
    [manufacturerid] => 
    [modelid] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_from] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_to] => 
    [hoursused_from] => 
    [hoursused_to] => 
    [horsepowers_from] => 
    [horsepowers_to] => 
    [price_from] => 
    [price_to] => 
    [colorid] => 
    [isdamaged] => 
)
</pre>
```

using the following code:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($formValues);
```

however, I am using pagination, and on the next page, when i try to access the variable using the following code:

```
print_r($formValues);
```

I get an empty array.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Please could you provide a missing code.

Comment: i will update my post in a minute...

Comment: hi, i added only the code relevant to the session, since controller is fairly large...can you spot why this array is not added in the session from this code? if not, i will upload whole controller, but it is...large...

Answer (score 1):

After you set an array to session data, you need to retrieve it by each item's key or retrieve all of the session data at once.

```
// adds the $formValues array to session data
$this->session->set_userdata($formValues);

// get a single item from the session data ($formValues['addtypeid'])
$addtypeid = $this->session->userdata('addtypeid');

// get all items from the session as an array
$formValues = $this->session->all_userdata();
```

Example of getting multiple specific items, but not all (from comments):

```
$formValues = array();
$formKeys = array('addtypeid', 'isnew', /* etc... */ );
foreach ($formKeys as $key)
{
    if ($this->session->userdata($key))
    {
        $formValues[$key] = $this->session->userdata($key);
    }
}
```

OR

```
$formValues = array(
    'addtypeid' => $this->session->userdata('addtypeid'),
    'isnew' => $this->session->userdata('isnew'),
    /* etc... */
);
```

One last edit based on comments:
Try setting the whole array to a single session item instead of individual session items.

```
// setting $formValues
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
    'formValues' => $formValues
));

// getting $formValues
// the if statement it to prevent it setting $formValues to false when the session data doesn't exist
if ($this->session->set_userdata('formValues'))
{
    $formValues = $this->session->set_userdata('formValues');
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, $formValues = $this->session->all_userdata(); returns all_userdata, hence the function name...i need only those variables stored in formValues...not alluserdata....

Comment: Then you'll have to get each one by name. You could loop any array that has the item names/keys to populate a new array. I'll edit the answer with an example.

Comment: Can you verify that the session data is being set? Print the result of `$this->session->all_userdata()` on the same page that's setting the session data (right after you set it), and then again on the second page to see if they match up.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what $formValues should be before getting the session data. Do you have any array that has the list of keys you need to get from the session data? If so, where is it set? You included the output in your question, but not where the keys come from.

Comment: keys come from the following line: $formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but is there post data to get on the second page?

Comment: no, that's why i want to place them in the session in the first page..which is actually the same controller.

Comment: Ok, so the post data is empty, then there is no list of keys to use, which is why the array would be empty. You have to have that list somewhere, or get them individually. I updated the answer again.

Comment: i am creating the form dynamicly ,so getting the individual values is not an option. going home, will try again tommorow to fix this somehow. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to retrieve all the session data items and reconstruct the array before you use it, so for example, since you have saved addtypeid by virtue of its includsion in the array you provided to the session then you can retrieve addtypeid with: `$this->session->userdata('addtypeid');`

Comment: steve, that code returns an empty array....sure enough since i am printing it from controller, i get bunch of errors header already sent, but array is empty...nothing is displayed when i use print_r

Comment: but if i print_r all_userdata, then values are there, but individualy,not as an array...that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have been able to solve the problem. Make sure the baseurl corresponds with the url you specify here.

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] =site_url('/events/viewevent/');
    $total= $this->db->get('event_tb');
```